# return bool as a value in bool operator[] in cpp

Tags: c++, boolean, return-value

So basically i have an std::vector container that contains bool values (true, false), and i need an operator[] for it, but when i return the value(bool) with the right index, it gives me an error like this:
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'bool&' to an rvalue of type 'bool'|

my operator looks like this:

```
bool& operator[] ( unsigned int idx) {
    typename std::vector<bool>::iterator retval;
    for (typename std::vector<std::vector<bool> *>::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it) {
        for (typename std::vector<bool>::iterator cont_it = (*it)->begin(); cont_it != (*it)->end(); ++cont_it) {
            if (idx == 0) {
                retval = cont_it;
            }
            idx--;
        }
    }
    return *retval;
}
```

and the call what gives error:

```
ivb[0] = false;
ivb[1] = true;
```

Comment: Unfortunately `std::vector<bool>` is [special](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). One way that's it's special is that you can't dereference a `std::vector<bool>::iterator` and get a `bool&`. I guess you should have something like `struct bool_wrapper { bool value; }` and then you can use `std::vector<bool_wrapper>` instead.

Comment: How about `auto` instead of `typename std::vector<std::vector<bool>*>::iterator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little performances improve to [@Jarod42 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972324/8038186):

```
std::vector<bool>::reference operator[](unsigned int idx) {
    for (auto &inner : data) {
        if (idx < inner.size()) {
            return inner[idx];
        }
        idx -= inner.size();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("out of range");
}
```

And assume all of the inner vectors are with the same size:

```
std::vector<bool>::reference operator[](unsigned int idx) {
    // vectors_sizes = data[0].size()
    if (idx >= vectors_sizes * data.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("out of range");
    return data[idx / vectors_sizes][idx % vectors_sizes];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std::vector might be special, with packing optimization (so its `operator[]` return wrapper/proxy class).

You might then forward the return value:

```
std::vector<bool>::reference operator[] ( unsigned int idx) { 
    for (auto& inner : data) {
        for (auto&& e : inner) {
            if (idx-- == 0) {
                return e;
            }
        }     
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("out of range");
}
```